# Map displays on Android 2.1 emulator but not on Android 2.1 mobile

Tags: android, android-maps

Android: Map displays on emulator(Version: Google APIs 2.1,level:7). But when uploaded into android mobile,it doesn't display

Hi All,

I have done one project in android which is to display map using GOOGLE API KEY.

goto: [http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android]

I generated MAP API key by following the procedure mentioned in above link correctly. It works well and **displays map on EMULATOR.**

I took BUILD of my project and uploaded into the android MOBILE. Here **Map DOESN'T display on my mobile**.

Don't know what is the reason behind this problem :(

My AVD Version Details:

AVD Name: Google APIs(Google Inc.)
Platform : 2.1
API Level: 7

My android Mobile Details:

It also supports GoogleAPI 2.1(Level 7) only. 
All other functionalities work well except displaying map.(I am getting Polylines only)

My XML file looks:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0l4sCTTyRmXTNo7k8DREHvEaLar2UmHGwnhZVHQ"
    />
```

Can anyone help me to recover this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Vansi

Answer (score 0):

check  internet connectivity in mobile.3g simple with two bar on device top.open browser in mobile give any address check the is it work fine.

If its work in emulator mean its surely work in device also . Just uninstall  ur app from device and reinstall again.check it will work fine ,also check ur manifest file when ur application loaded into ur device you must set android:debuggable as true.

Comment: the internet connection works fine.also i am able to open the Google's Maps Application in my mobile and it works very fine.But in my application the map is not getting displayed

Comment: can u give me any other help or suggestions.i want to submit this project as early as possible